# Prediction of multiple time series of different lengths

Tags: forecasting

I have multiple store sales time series where seasonality is, or should be, correlated, but the time series are of differing lengths (e.g. 6 months vs 3.5 years). Forecasting the longer time series works well, but for the shorter time series obvious seasonality components are missing.

Is there a straight forward way to "borrow" seasonality information from the longer time series and apply it to the shorter time series?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Are you familiar with time series decomposition? Whatever software you’re using will have the ability to do. It can separate your longer time series into components like level, error, trend and seasonality.

Let’s assume your time series do not have equal means/levels. One important thing will be to get the decomposed seasonality in *multiplicative* terms not additive. This will make it a percent, rather than nominal. If you had annual data with weekly seasonality you can get 52 percentages, one per week.

If you then forecast and decompose your shorter series the seasonal index can be multiplied against the level to get a seasonally adjusted level.